# how can I get the length of an video in order to validate django form before upload can begin?

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, django-forms

I have an app running on heroku that allows users to upload videos, then I use ffmpeg to preform 3 tasks using celery and redis-to-go:

```
1) Check the format and if it isn't already mp4, convert it to mp4.
2) Extract a 3 minute clip, in mp4 format
3) Grab an image from the video
```

The problem is that I want to verify the video length before the video is uploaded and the three tasks are run since I want to make sure all videos are at least 15 minutes, and if not I want to raise a ValidationError. So when validating the form, I want to do something like this:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):        
    data = super(ContentTypeRestrictedVideoField, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

    file = data.file
    try:
        content_type = file.content_type
        main, extension = content_type.split('/')
        if content_type in self.content_types:
            if file._size > self.max_upload_size:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please keep filesize under %s. Current filesize %s') % (filesizeformat(self.max_upload_size), filesizeformat(file._size)))
            if VIDEO_LENGTH < MINIMUM_LENGTH:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('Please make sure video file is at least %s. Current video length %s') % (MINIMUM_LENGTH, VIDEO_LENGTH)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('File type is not supported. File must be mov, flv, avi, mpeg, wmv, or mp4.'))
    except AttributeError:
        pass        

    return data
```

What could I do for VIDEO_LENGTH and MINIMUM_LENGTH? I read that ffprobe could be used for getting the duration, but it isn't available with the buildpack I am using and I am very inexperienced. I can't just validate file size because it can vary greatly depending on numerous factors. Anyone have any solution as to what I could try? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to know the length of a video without uploading it. That code should live then in the client machine.

The only code you may execute in the client machine is Javascript and maybe:

1. Flash
2. Java applets
3. Any other (browser plugin dependent) client side logic.

This is the only way I see to accomplish the task you want and of course, you cannot assume every browser have the extension needed nor the client have `ffmpeg` installed.

IMHO I don't think you can achieve the task that way. You should upload the file, validate it and if validation doesn't pass, then delete it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Although it isn't what I wanted to hear, it does help because now I know I can't do it the way I have been trying to do it.

Comment: You're welcome. I know is bad news but I just don't see a way to do that. In addition, you can warn your users not to upload a video larger than 15 min, and when he/she does it, you just discard it in the server side. The user is guilty and wasted his/her time for not reading the warning :)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to accomplish this using moviepy.

My use-case is a bit different, but the principle should be the same.

```
from moviepy.editor import *


def video_form_upload(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        # 'upload' is the name of the input field
        vid = request.FILES['upload']
        clip = VideoFileClip(vid.temporary_file_path())
        obj.duration = clip.duration
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/video/")
else:
    form = VideoForm()
context = {
    "form": form
}
return render(request, 'html/media/upload.html', context)
```